# How do you hyphenate "Lagrangian"?

Tags: hyphenation, technical, french

This is a proper noun (used extensively in physics) named after [a French monsieur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph-Louis_Lagrange). How should this word be hyphenated? Should it follow English or French pronunciation rules, or something else?

Comment: In general, if it's not absolutely necessary, don't.

Comment: What has your research shown you about how the term is already used?

Comment: @livresque For instance, [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/classical_mechanics/4YblBaliPeAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=lagrangian)'s usage from a classical mechanics textbook. [Here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mechanics/bE-9tUH2J2wC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=Lagrangian)'s another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go your style guide.

The Chicago Manual of Style (CMoS, 13th ed.) says:

> *Word division*. The fundamental principle of French word division is to divide as far as possible on a vowel, avoiding consonantal ending of syllables except where *n* nasalizes a preceding vowel:

> a-che-ter

> in-di-vi-si-bi-li-té

> ba-lan-cer (*not* bal-an-cer)

> ta-bleau (*not* tab-leau)

(Section 9.27)

While it is better to not divide a proper name, word division for a French word might be:

> La-gran-gi-an

Comment: This is in the English CMoS?

Comment: Correct. The (AmE) Chicago Manual of Style has a section on dividing foreign languages, including French.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Sounds more bipolar to me.

Comment: I honestly went to CMoS looking for Word Division, but saw the subcategory for French and thought: Best of both worlds.

Comment: Luckily, English and French hyphenation rules agree in the case of *La-gran-gi-an.* Compare [in-tan-gi-ble](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intangible) and [Car-o-lin-gi-an](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Carolingian)

Comment: If this is foreign language advice ('word division for a French word might be'), it is off-topic on ELU.  But 'Lagrangian' is in the English lexis; do you mean 'word division for a loanword from French is'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth To be honest, I'm not sure if it is classified as a loanword or an anglicized French word. I've only encountered usage of this word so far in English textbooks, regardless of the author being a native English speaker or not (the second textbook example I put in the OP, by Landau & Lifshitz, is translated from Russian). Unfortunately I don't speak French myself, other than "bonjour", "baguette", and "je ne sans quoi"...

Comment: If it's in a reasonable dictionary (OED; Lexico, AHD, M-W ...) it's in the lexicon. If it's not, the question is off-topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: is the question of how to hyphenate foreign words in English text really off-topic? For example, Russian and Japanese don't have foreign hyphenation rules you can apply.

Comment: @Peter Shor A foreign word inserted into a sentence is like an emoticon or illuminated letter  (or diagram) so inserted.

Answer (score 0):

As you remark, *Lagrangian* is used as a noun; it is a mathematical function that encapsulates the dynamics of a mechanical system. It is also used adjectivally to describe a way of dealing with motion of objects, different from a Newtonian way, for example.

It is not clear from your question why you would wish to use the word in a hyphenated construction. One acceptable example might be

> "Lagrangian-inspired"
>
> [MITpressjournals](https://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/978-0-262-31050-5-ch021)

In this case the author followed the usual rule for hyphenation, creating a compound adjective.

In decades of Physics I have always heard the word pronounced in manner of the French name *Lagrange* or in an Anglicised  manner where the each bold "a" in "L**a**gr**a**ngian" is short and of similar sound. I regret that I am not competent to express this part of the answer in conventional phonetics.

Comment: I think he wants to hyphenate it between lines.  "Lagran-" on one line and "gian" on the next.  Or should it be Lagrang-ian ?  The first was found in an old journal by livresque

Comment: Good guess. One can often overcome the difficulty easily in modern publishing packages by specifying no hyphenation or by altering spacing slightly.

Comment: Yes, @GEdgar is right, I wanted to hyphenate it between lines. I agree with Anton that all my physics professors seem to pronounce it as /lə 'gränʒ i ən/. (Side note: I wish inputting IPA symbols is easier here. I had to go through Character Map manually on a Unicode font...)